# Replace design with least amount of votes

Tags: javascript

I have a voting based system using javascript and local storage to save the designs & votes. I'd like a way to replace the design with the least amount of votes.

Currently I'm prepending a clone of the design to the start of the DOM, which obviously pushes the votes out of order and leaves me with more than 6 designs in the gallery.

Also I'm not sure of the logic if two designs have the same amount of votes?

Any hep would be appreciated.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/fuzzyduck/pen/jOpzwXp

```
    //variables for tracking votes
    let voteVal1 = Number(localStorage.getItem("voteVal1"))
    let voteVal2 = Number(localStorage.getItem("voteVal2"))
    let voteVal3 = Number(localStorage.getItem("voteVal3"))
    let voteVal4 = Number(localStorage.getItem("voteVal4"))
    let voteVal5 = Number(localStorage.getItem("voteVal5"))
    let voteVal6 = Number(localStorage.getItem("voteVal6"))

    //log votes on load
    console.log("Votes for 1: " +voteVal1)
    console.log("Votes for 2: " +voteVal2)
    console.log("Votes for 3: " +voteVal3)
    console.log("Votes for 4: " +voteVal4)
    console.log("Votes for 5: " +voteVal5)
    console.log("Votes for 6: " +voteVal6)

    //display votes on load
    $(".voteVal1").html(voteVal1)
    $(".voteVal2").html(voteVal2)
    $(".voteVal3").html(voteVal3)
    $(".voteVal4").html(voteVal4)
    $(".voteVal5").html(voteVal5)
    $(".voteVal6").html(voteVal6)

    //increase votes
    $(".btn1").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal1", ++voteVal1)
      $(".voteVal1").html(voteVal1)
    })
    $(".btn2").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal2", ++voteVal2)
      $(".voteVal2").html(voteVal2)
    })
    $(".btn3").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal3", ++voteVal3)
      $(".voteVal3").html(voteVal3)
    })
    $(".btn4").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal4", ++voteVal4)
      $(".voteVal4").html(voteVal4)
    })
    $(".btn5").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal5", ++voteVal5)
      $(".voteVal5").html(voteVal5)
    })
    $(".btn6").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal6", ++voteVal6)
      $(".voteVal6").html(voteVal6)
    })

    $(".resetAllVotes").on("click", function () {
      localStorage.setItem("voteVal1", 0)
      $(".voteVal1").html(0)

      localStorage.setItem("voteVal2", 0)
      $(".voteVal2").html(0)

      localStorage.setItem("voteVal3", 0)
      $(".voteVal3").html(0)

      localStorage.setItem("voteVal4", 0)
      $(".voteVal4").html(0)

      localStorage.setItem("voteVal5", 0)
      $(".voteVal5").html(0)

      localStorage.setItem("voteVal6", 0)
      $(".voteVal6").html(0)
    })

    //set colours on load
    $(".container div").each(function(index) {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass(localStorage.getItem(String(index))).addClass("circle")
    })

    //change colours
    $(".btnred").on("click", function () {
      $("#main").removeClass().addClass("red")
      localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'red')
    })
    $(".btnblue").on("click", function () {
      $("#main").removeClass().addClass("blue")
      localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'blue')
    })
    $(".btnpurple").on("click", function () {
      $("#main").removeClass().addClass("purple")
      localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'purple')
    })

    $(".clone").on("click", function () {
      //the below has already been created in v1 - this is just for testing
      $("#main").clone().removeClass("main").prependTo(".container")
      $(".container div").each(function(index) {
        localStorage.setItem(index, this.className)
      })
      //remove design with least votes (this is where the fun begins)
      voting();
    })

    function voting(){
      //new design will currently pre-pend to top left - but it should replace the design with the lowest score
      //we then need to reset the voteVal to zero on the new design

      //check which the lowest score (what if they have the same score?)
      let pos1Check = [voteVal2,voteVal3,voteVal4,voteVal5,voteVal6];
      if(voteVal1 > Math.min.apply(null, pos1Check)) {
        console.log("Pos1: higher");
      } else {
        console.log("Pos1: lower");
      }

      //if pos2 fails we can remove it as it likely to have to least votes
      let pos2Check = [voteVal1,voteVal3,voteVal4,voteVal5,voteVal6];
      if(voteVal2 > Math.min.apply(null, pos2Check)) {
        console.log("Pos2: higher");
      } else {
        console.log("Pos2: lower");
      }

      let pos3Check = [voteVal1,voteVal2,voteVal4,voteVal5,voteVal6];
      if(voteVal3 > Math.min.apply(null, pos3Check)) {
        console.log("Pos3: higher");
      } else {
        console.log("Pos3: lower");
      }

      let pos4Check = [voteVal1,voteVal2,voteVal3,voteVal5,voteVal6];
      if(voteVal4 > Math.min.apply(null, pos4Check)) {
        console.log("Pos4: higher");
      } else {
        console.log("Pos4: lower");
      }

      let pos5Check = [voteVal1,voteVal2,voteVal3,voteVal4,voteVal6];
      if(voteVal5 > Math.min.apply(null, pos5Check)) {
        console.log("Pos5: higher");
      } else {
        console.log("Pos5: lower");
      }

      let pos6Check = [voteVal1,voteVal2,voteVal3,voteVal4,voteVal5];
      if(voteVal6 > Math.min.apply(null, pos6Check)) {
        console.log("Pos6: higher");
      } else {
        console.log("Pos6: lower");
      }
    }
```

Comment: I can't really figure out what the problem is. Sorting things based on an attribute (call it "votes" or "beauty", it does not change the code much) can be achieved with a call to `sort`; and if you only have space for N elements, you simply pick the 1st N after sorting (this takes care of "equally ranked" elements). If the true question boils down to "I want to show only the top N elements based on an attribute", your question *can* be answered easily - please clarify. And remove the "local-storage" and "voting" tags, as they would not meaningfully contribute to the question.

Comment: You can use `array` instead of using voteVal1, voteVal2..etc. Then Sort the array on each vote button clicked and display.